# How to apply multiple filters on a Django template variable?

Tags: python, django

For me this works:

> {{ game.description|safe }}

But this fails:

```
{{ game.description|safe|slice:"65" }}
```

Is there a way to apply two or more filters on a variable in Django templates?

Comment: This should work. For example, `{{ var|safe|escape }}` works and is used in the docs. What is your exact error? Why is your slice `65`?

Comment: Nothing appears when I try the second. It's 65 because in case the game description is too long for the container div.

Comment: just switch the order of the filters. more detail in my answer below.

Answer (score 46):

Although it's quite past when the OP posted the question, but for other people that may need the info, this seems to work well for me:

You can rewrite

```
{{ game.description|safe|slice:"65" }}
```

as

```
{% with description=game.description|safe %}
{{description|slice:"65"}}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Second version worked for me but, I had to use my custom filter before using 'safe'.

Answer (score 11):

Is description an array or a string?

If it is a string, you might want to try `truncatewords` (or `truncatewords_html` if the description can contain HTML),

```
{{ game.description|safe|truncatewords:65 }}
```

Reference: *[Built-in filter reference, truncatewords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatewords)*.

(I'm new to Django so my apologies if slice works on strings.)

Answer (score 3):

change

```
{{ game.description|safe|slice:"65" }}
```

to

```
{{ game.description|safe|slice:":65" }}
```

you are missing the colon

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
{% filter force_escape|lower %}
    This text will be HTML-escaped, and will appear in all lowercase.
{% endfilter %}
```

Reference: *[Built-in tag reference, filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#filter)*.