# Using multiple filters for django text?

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-filters

I have a model called article that has a field for the content of the article:

```
content     = RichTextField()
```

I am trying to add two filters to it: safe and linebreaks. However when I do this:

```
{{article.content|safe|linebreaks}}
```

Only the first filter works. Does anyone know the syntax to use multiple filters?

Thanks y'all!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply multiple filters on a Django template variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281404/how-to-apply-multiple-filters-on-a-django-template-variable)

Comment: Yes, this answers it. Sorry, I probably should have searched StackOverflow first! I'm new here